# KVM gets background and mouse with gdm3 and lightdm on debian wheezy

Tags: gnome

I have a debian wheezy system with a ipkvm. I originally installed it as a none gdm server. I then installed gnome-desktop-environment and rebooted. The kvm just shows the background and mouse and a black box in the middle. Is there anything I can do make the display visible and usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the sync rate to one that was compatible with my KVM.